# Compare script using awk and bash

Tags: bash, linux, awk

I try to create compare script using awk and another command and running successful.

But I think the script I create it's to long.

Is there anyone can shorten my script below ?

After plan A `shorten the code than`, plan B is :

```
 1. I want eliminated a lot temp file (.txt), only need `lengkap.txt`
 2. Put command in variable if can
```

It's my pleasure if anyone can help me

Below is the code that I create based searching and trying.

```
#!/bin/bash

### Path Folder who will be compare ###
path1=/home/rio/apps1
path2=/home/rio/apps2

### Find all filename and convert to MD5 ###
find $path1 -type f | xargs md5sum > checksums.md5
find $path2 -type f | xargs md5sum > checksums2.md5

### Compare to find different folder ###
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' checksums.md5 checksums2.md5 > hasil1.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' checksums2.md5 checksums.md5 > hasil2.txt

### Merge result of compare ###
awk '{print $0}' hasil1.txt hasil2.txt > perbedaan.txt

### Filter Just Filename Difference ###
cat perbedaan.txt | awk '{print $2}' > hasilperbedaan.txt

### File about result compare (just filename) ###
cekhasil=/home/rio/hasilperbedaan.txt

### Check if File result compare empty or not ###
if [ -s "$cekhasil" ]
then 
   echo " file exists and is not empty "
    ### Find All filename and date, after that put as we want ###
    find $path1 -type f -ls | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }' > filedate1.txt
    find $path2 -type f -ls | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }' > filedate2.txt

    ### Compare to get the date of filename ###
    awk 'A[$1]++' hasilperbedaan.txt filedate1.txt > pre_hasil1.txt
    awk 'A[$1]++' hasilperbedaan.txt filedate2.txt > pre_hasil2.txt
    ### Merge result of compare with date ###
    awk '{print $0}' pre_hasil1.txt pre_hasil2.txt > lengkap.txt
else
   echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review Stack Exchange! You might find useful the advice on choosing a good title for a question. You can edit yours. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please tell us what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: one thing that seems fishy about the script is that it writes a lot of files in cwd, which are all not cleaned after the job is done.

Comment: @pacmaninbw it's for compare folder with different server but same folder (example : apps).

Comment: @hjpotter92, yes, I think so too. That's why need advice to shorten the script.

Comment: Please add `it's for compare folder with different server but same folder (example : apps)` to the question to make it clearer. Perhaps with a little more explanation.

Comment: if an answer solves your issue,  it would be nice to accept it. This will make your question and answer more visible...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it took time to figure out what your program is doing. So I did shorten it in two phases.

First phase: I removed all duplicate temporary files, and used a pipe when a temp file was used once.

STEP1: you just make a checksum of all files in $path1 and $path2

```
### Find all filename and convert to MD5 ###
find $path1 -type f | xargs md5sum > checksums.md5
find $path2 -type f | xargs md5sum > checksums2.md5
```

You don't need 2 temp files, as path is included in filename. So you can replace this with a single `find`. I use `sort` to be able to use uniq afterwards:

```
find "$path1" "$path2" -type f | xargs md5sum  | sort > cksum.md5
```

STEP2: you find unique checksums in both files, and get the corresponding filenames.

```
### Compare to find different folder ###
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' checksums.md5 checksums2.md5 > hasil1.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' checksums2.md5 checksums.md5 > hasil2.txt

### Merge result of compare ###
awk '{print $0}' hasil1.txt hasil2.txt > perbedaan.txt

### Filter Just Filename Difference ###
cat perbedaan.txt | awk '{print $2}' > hasilperbedaan.txt
```

As we have a checksum-sorted file, we just filter with `uniq`, and get filenames.

**Note**: As we use a MD5 checksum (128 bits), length is 128bits / 8bits * 2hex=32

```
uniq -u -w32 cksum.md5 | awk '{print $2}' > "$cekhasil"
```

If you prefer awk to uniq, just compare previous record's $1 with current's.

STEP 3: you match found entries with a new search (`find`) in the two source paths.

```
if [ -s "$cekhasil" ]
then
    echo " file exists and is not empty "
    ### Find All filename and date, after that put as we want ###
    find $path1 -type f -ls | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }' > filedate1.txt
    find $path2 -type f -ls | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }' > filedate2.txt

    ### Compare to get the date of filename ###
    awk 'A[$1]++' hasilperbedaan.txt filedate1.txt > pre_hasil1.txt
    awk 'A[$1]++' hasilperbedaan.txt filedate2.txt > pre_hasil2.txt
    ### Merge result of compare with date ###
    awk '{print $0}' pre_hasil1.txt pre_hasil2.txt > lengkap.txt
else
    echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
fi
```

Here, it is better to avoid new full `find`, and just loop over filenames.

```
if [ -s "$cekhasil" ]
then
    echo " file exists and is not empty "
    while read -r fn ; do
        ls -dils "$fn" | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }'
    done < "$cekhasil" > lengkap2.txt

else
    echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
fi
```

Alltogether, the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

path1=/home/br/dev/tools/bash
path2=/home/br/dev/tools/bash2
outfile=hasilperbedaan.txt

find "$path1" "$path2" -type f | xargs md5sum  | sort > cksum.md5

uniq -u -w32 cksum.md5 | awk '{print $2}' > "$outfile"

if [ -s "$outfile" ]; then
    echo " file exists and is not empty "
    while read -r fn ; do
        ls -dils "$fn" | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }'
    done < "$output" > lengkap2.txt

else
    echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
fi
```

At this point, we can notice the 2 remaining temp files are used only once. We just get rid of them, and just `pipe` all together to get the output file.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    path1=/home/br/dev/tools/bash
    path2=/home/br/dev/tools/bash2
    outputfile="lengkap-v2.txt"
    
    find "$path1" "$path2" -type f | xargs md5sum  | sort |
        uniq -u -w32 | awk '{print $2}' |
        while read -r fn ; do
            ls -dils "$fn" | awk '{print $11" "$8" "$9" "$10 }'
        done > "$outputfile"
    [[ -s "$outputfile" ]] && echo " file exists and is not empty " ||
            echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
```

**Notes**:

- I don't understand your second question: "Put command in variable if
  can", so I skip that one.
- You should **never** use the output of `find` (except with `-print0` options) or `ls` as input of any command. But it is out of scope for this answer.